# Get array from jquery post in pickadate plugin

Tags: jquery, arrays, post

I cannot figure out how to get an array from a jquery post returned back to **disable**.

**Update:** I have updated to code below. This is now returning **[true,[2014,1,28]]** inside my console.log which is the correct format. Refer to http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm#disable-dates for verification of the format.

My question now is why won't **return data;** place the code correctly in the disable: option? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var id_01 = $('[name="id_01"]').val();
var id_02 = $('[name="id_02"]').val();

function get_the_dates(id_01, id_02) {
    postData = {action: 'get-schedule-dates', id_01: id_01, id_02: id_02};

    $.post("somefile.php", postData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });

}

$('#appt_date_picker').pickadate({
    today: '',
    format: 'Date selecte!d: dddd, dd mmm, yyyy',
    formatSubmit: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    disable: get_the_dates(id_01, id_02)
});
```

Comment: basically, all I need to do is get the value returned from the function to the disable: option. How can I pass a variable to the pickadate plugin so that I can use it for the "disable" value?

Answer (score 0):

To solve that issue you have to check some things first

1. **somefile.php** have to return the date you want to disable, if you want to disable more than one date you have to use JSON encoding.
2. In the format property just use **'dddd, dd mmm, yyyy'**
3. In the case of dateArr you can't use that var cause is not global.

Hope that help you.

Comment: I updated the code.The POST is returning the correct json formatted array. I verified this in my console log. It's just not returning it correctly to the disable: object

Comment: 2. the format does not affect the function array. It is the format for how the text is displayed in the input field after a selection has been made.